# Failed to resolve: com.squareup.retrofit2.retrofit:2.9.0

Tags: java, android, retrofit2

build gradle (module) reports;
Failed to resolve squareup retrofit2 2.9.0
Failed to resolve squareup retrofit2 converter-gson 2.7.2

Am using java on
Android Studio Dolphin | 2021.3.1 Patch 1
Build #AI-213.7172.25.2113.9123335, built on September 30, 2022
Runtime version: 11.0.13+0-b1751.21-8125866 amd64
VM: OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM by JetBrains

Thanks

I tried checking stack over flow answers and found what was said is okay by my settings.

Comment: Can you post your build.gradle files and settings.gradle?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.